# Usage of <link> tag to refer to an external CSS file not working, what I did wrong?

Tags: html, css

I'm following the tutorial on the w3school for HTML and I'm stuck at the external linking part where you can include in your HTML page the CSS file you with the stylesheet defined by you with the `<link>` tag.

I have tried:

- adding in the correct way the arguments rel, href, type, or media
- clearing the cache from the browser, maybe it saved some old code but it was not the case
- creating another .css file to try and code different style solutions

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="whiteonblack.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </style>
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

whiteonblack.css

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    color:  white;
}
```

The body background should be completely black (I hate bright websites, even if this is for testing and with awful and old yet working (but not so much) HTML) and the general text to be white. Also some love from the community for DIY students :).

It defaults to the reverse, white bg and black text. God the hate.

Comment: Did you put whiteonblack.css and index.html in same folder?

Comment: @HienNguyen Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `link` tag belongs in the `head` tag directly. Do not nest it in a `style` tag; that's meant for actual CSS.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="whiteonblack.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```

Comment: I was following the tutorial "inertially" and totally forgot to look for the whole tutorial snippet so I left the <style> tag as it was not mentioned that you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style tag. Use below CSS code.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="whiteonblack.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```